# How to compute an average of std of data?

Tags: standard-deviation

My research data contains mean and Std of voice pitch of ten sentences for each participants.

60 depressed participants are digitaly recorded and the first ten sentences of each participatns are acoustically analyzed. each of the ten sentences is acoustically anlayzed to yeild the measure of F0 (pitch) std and F0 mean (among other acoustic varibles).  The final data file wil have one row for each participtans, aggregating the data of the ten sentences. the question is about the F0 std which is valuble varible, since it contains info about emotional regulation. So, how should I compute the one-row F0 std measure? by avaraging the 10 std of F0? or by calculating the the std of the 10 means of the f0?

How can I compute the average std of the ten sentences? is it the mean of the 10 std, or I should compute the std of the 10 means? or both?

Comment: What exactly do you need to compute? What for?

Comment: The research tries to predict deprssion levels from pich (fundmetnal frequency) of the patients voice. I belive that the std of the pitch is the exact measure to predict it.

Comment: You need to tell us more about your data and your study. Otherwise this is unanswerable because there is no rule that says that you always compute mean of sd's etc.

Comment: Ok, 60 participants are digitaly recorded and the first ten sentences of each participatns are acoustically analyzed. each of the ten sentences is acoustically decoded on F0 (pitch) std and F0 mean, among other acoustic varibles.

Comment: Ok, 60 participants are digitaly recorded and the first ten sentences of each participatns are acoustically analyzed. each of the ten sentences is acoustically decoded on F0 (pitch) std and F0 mean, among other acoustic varibles. the final data file wil have one row for each participtans aggregating the data of the ten sentences. the question is about the F0 std which is valuble varible, since it contains info about emotional regulation. So, how should I compute the one-row F0 std measure? by avaraging the 10 std of F0? or by calculating the the std of the 10 means of the f0?